# vNext Model Binder that filter strings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding, modelbinders

I need to filter all strings in my project to prevent XSS attacks.
I decided to do it by using global model binder.
Below you can see model binder registration code:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().AddMvcOptions(options =>
    {
        options.ModelBinders.Add(new AntiXSSModelBinder());
    });
}
```

The requirement is to filter both simple parameter strings and strings that inside complex type (any level of nesting):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetShippingAddress(string id)
public async Task<IActionResult> AddUpdateShippingMethod(AddUpdateShippingMethodModel model)
// AddUpdateShippingMethodModel has Text property of string type
```

Example of filtering method:

```
public class AntiXSSModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task<ModelBindingResult> BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        // ...
    }

    private string FilterPotentiallyXSSEntries(string value)
    {
        return value.Replace("<", "").Replace(">", "").Replace("script", "");
    }
}
```

No good documentation on ModelBinder topic, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I feel you're doing this backwards. The general best practice is to encode at the point of output, be it views, an XML serializer, a JSON serializer or whatever. Instead you're locking your data into HTML, your filter is ineffective depending on where your data ends up, and worse, when you use razor you're run the risk of double encoding should you decide to encode to entities, rather than replace with a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class AntiXSSModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task<ModelBindingResult> BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelMetadata.IsComplexType)
        {
            // this type cannot be converted
            return ModelBindingResult.NoResultAsync;
        }

        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            // no entry
            return ModelBindingResult.NoResultAsync;
        }

        var model = valueProviderResult.ConvertTo(bindingContext.ModelType);

        if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(string))
        {
            var modelAsString = model as string;

            if (model != null)
            {
                return ModelBindingResult.SuccessAsync(bindingContext.ModelName, FilterPotentiallyXSSEntries(modelAsString));
            }
        }

        return ModelBindingResult.NoResultAsync;
    }

    private static string FilterPotentiallyXSSEntries(string value)
    {
        return value.Replace("<", "").Replace(">", "").Replace("script", "");
    }
}
```

Works for all levels of nesting.